# VSCode extension publishing: Extension failed Virus check. Please submit a valid extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to release v1.7.1 of this extension: https://github.com/lhl2617/VSLilyPond

The release automation (on GitHub actions) can be found running successfully here: https://github.com/lhl2617/VSLilyPond/runs/3575219458

However, on my extension publishers page I obtain the following:

[image]

Clicking on the Error link gives

[image]

How do I get more information on how my extension is failing this check?

Comment: You might use `vsce package` to generate the installer and upload to a typical site like https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload where all major anti-virus software products are used to scan for issues.

Comment: @LexLi Investigative work needed, but I found the offending change--a node module that contains some binaries. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @LhLee Either post the answer or close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaging the extension using vsce package and uploading to a typical site like virustotal.com/gui/home/upload where all major anti-virus software products are used to scan for issues found the root cause.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  virustotal doesn't report any issues with my extension, though.